# ASR1006 Link Down Due to Remote Fault

Tags: cisco, router, fiber

We have 10G fiber running since 1 year but today I have migrate that same link to ASR1006 and I am seeing following error, what could be the problem?

```
Oct  7 17:29:48.211: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to remote fault
Oct  7 17:29:48.424: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to local fault
Oct  7 17:29:48.623: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to local fault
Oct  7 17:29:48.642: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to remote fault
Oct  7 17:29:48.863: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to remote fault
Oct  7 17:29:48.943: %IOSXE_SPA-6-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, link down due to remote fault
Oct  7 17:29:50.204: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, changed state to down
Oct  7 17:29:50.208: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: SIP1/1: Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0, changed state to down
```

SPA status looks good

```
#show hw-module subslot all oir
Module        Model                Operational Status
------------- -------------------- ------------------------
subslot 0/0   SPA-1X10GE-L-V2      ok
subslot 0/3   SPA-1X10GE-L-V2      ok
subslot 1/0   SPA-1X10GE-L-V2      ok
subslot 1/1   SPA-1X10GE-L-V2      ok
```

Interface output

```
#sh int te1/1/0
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0 is down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is SPA-1X10GE-L-V2, address is f4cf.e2ed.8750 (bia f4cf.e2ed.8750)
  Description: 
  Internet address is 69.25.205.158/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not supported
  Full Duplex, 10000Mbps, link type is force-up, media type is 10GBase-LR
  output flow-control is on, input flow-control is on
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/375/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 0 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 11 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

## UPDATE

This is very interesting, same fiber I moved back to C3850 switch and it works! but if I moved back to ASR1006 it didn't work.

But if I connect ASR1006 same fiber port to C3850 back to back (1 meter distance) and assign random IP to test ping and it work!

SPF model is `Cisco XFP-10GLR-OC192SR`

What could be the issue?

Comment: I have opened cisco TAC to see, they are saying move port to other `SPA` to check. i will let you know once i do that

Comment: Did you ever hear back from Cisco TAC regarding this?

Comment: Yes it was faulty SIP/SPA module, they replace hardware.

Comment: Add an answer below and accept it then so that the question doesn’t keep popping up :)

Comment: Please add an answer and accept it so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

it was faulty SIP/SPA module, cisco replace hardware.